# AccessViolationError Was Unhandled

Tags: c#, ms-access, vsto

I am using the below code -- well trying to at least.  But I can't I get a Access Violation Error when it hits the OpenCurrentDatabase Line. "Attempted to read or write protected memory.  This is often an indication of the other memory is corrupt"

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAcc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
oAcc.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\\Test\\Test.mdb", false, "");
oAcc.DoCmd.RunSQL("Select empName, empAddress, empPhone FROM employeeInfo");
oAcc.DoCmd.Save(AcObjectType.acQuery, "Query_Built_Via_C#");
```

EDIT ----------------
And the database is closed when I attempt to run this command.

Comment: do you have the mdb file open otherwise (on your desktop)?

Comment: @Brad no the database file is not opened when I run the procedure.  Also, I verified that it is a valid file location and everything is spelled properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you are using looks good.  I think this issue is that you are using the @ and escaping the slashes.  You should use one or the other, but not both.

Try this instead.
    @"C:\Test\Test.mdb"

Comment: Just tried both instances, one with the escape character and using the @ symbol and same error.

Comment: I have found some indication that users had this specific issue with multiple versions of office installed or in upgrading VS.  I would suggest trying to search for the method you are calling and the error you receive to see if anyone has found a solution.

Comment: I have both Office 2000 and Office 2010 installed so that very well could be my issue.  Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Those end up being pretty tricky.  I found one reference that indicated they were able to get it to work using late binding.  You may give that a try.